Filling and Substituting in R Loop
I organized a loop to calculate a new bus fleet within a budget.
BUS TYPE: PADRON, PRICE: 1KK; BUS TYPE: MEDIO, PRICE: 800k.
In this example I am allocating the budget to new types of PADRON, replacing the oldest ones in the fleet.
I want to replace the PADRON type with the MEDIUM type, cheaper, but not as big.
Then I must also consider a Compensation Factor (CF) of 1.114 (i.e., 01 PADRON is equivalent, in terms of passenger capacity, to 1.114 MEDIUM). In a way I will not substitute 01 PADRON for every new MEDIO.
budget<-seq(25000000,1000000000,by=25000000)
colnames(cost)<-c("TP","COST_UN")
fleet<-merge(fleet,cost,by.x="TP",by.y="TP")
fleet <- fleet %>% mutate(index = row_number())
dados_duplicados <- fleet %>% slice(rep(1:n(), NUM)) %>% select(-NUM) 
fleet<-arrange(dados_duplicados,TP,ANO)
fleet$index<-NULL
fleet$ID<-c(1:nrow(fleet))
fleet2<-fleet



for(i in 1:length(budget)){
  fleet<-fleet4
  fleet2<-fleet
  
  for(j in 2024:2028){
    fleet3<-rbind(filter(fleet2,TP=="PADRON"))
    fleet3<-arrange(fleet3,TP,ANO)
    cost_rent<-0
    cost_purchase<-0
    
    while(cost_rent<=budget[i]){
      rent<-fleet3[1,]
      fleet3[1,]<-NA
      fleet3<-filter(fleet3,!is.na(TP))
      if(j==2024){
        rent$ANO<-j
        rent$AGE<-0
      }
      fleet3<-rbind(fleet3,rent)
      cost_rent<- cost_rent+(rent$COST_UN[1])*(1.2)*(0.025)*(12)
    }
    
    while(cost_purchase<=budget[i]){
      sell<-fleet3[1,]
      fleet3[1,]<-NA
      fleet3<-filter(fleet3,!is.na(TP))
      sell$ANO<-j
      sell$AGE<-0
      fleet3<-rbind(fleet3,sell)
      cost_purchase<-cost_purchase+(sell$COST_UN[1])
    }
    
    fleet2<-filter(fleet2,!ID %in% fleet3$ID)
    fleet2<-rbind(fleet2,fleet3)
    fleet2$CURRENT_YEAR<-j
    if(j==2024){
      fleet<-fleet2
    }else{
      fleet<-rbind(fleet,fleet2)
    }
    
  }
  fleet$budget<-budget[i]
  fleet$AGE<-fleet$CURRENT_YEAR-fleet$ANO
  write.csv2(fleet,str_c('Subs_MEDIO_',budget[i],'.csv'),row.names = F)
}

setwd('..')

